# How to compress fs.createReadStream in express

Tags: node.js, express, compression

I have this code;

```
const express = require('express')
const compression = require('compression')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3003;

app.use(compression())
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/src/index/index.html').pipe(res);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Portfolio listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

In chrome dev tools the `app.js` file that is requested in the `index.html` is gzipped but the first file (the `index.html` referred to in the code above) is not.

How do I compress the `index.html` file before it is streamed?

Comment: I think using compression middleware should already take care of that. How have you verified that the compression is missing?

Comment: In chrome dev tools content-encoding is empty for the index.html file but says gzip for the JS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `zlib` module:

```
fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/src/index/index.html')
  .pipe(zlib.createGzip())
  .pipe(res);
```